# How to have a customer login hosted on tomcat using Jekyll?

Tags: tomcat, web, content-management-system, jekyll

I am creating a website for someone and I am using Jekyll as my CMS. I cannot find on Jekyll documentation how to set a client or customer login, so the customer can login and basically blog, without having to have a developer updating his site constantly. Is there a way to set up that up on Tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of Joshua Morris is correct.

Another user friendly way of letting clients blog in a Jekyll site is to use CloudCannon (http://cloudcannon.com). You can upload your Jekyll site there and let Cloudcannon push the static site to your Tomcat (or any other) server. The service got a free plan, that is sufficient for this solution.

PS. I am not related to CloudCannon, but I am a very happy user (and customer).

Comment: What do you mean make Cloud Cannon push it to my Tomcat? I tried cloud cannon and it's great! My problem is I need to host a webapp that does some advanced functions and calls we services. You are saying I can build it with Cloud cannon and direct it to my Tomcat and still have the user able to update?

Comment: You can let CloudCannon push the STATIC files to your Tomcat server and let clients update your website at CloudCannon. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes it does! I tried to find the instructions for that in the cloud cannon website and couldn't find it. What is the name of the service?

Comment: Go to your site in CloudCannon > Site settings > Storage provider

Comment: my friend, you are a genius! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Jekyll is for developing static sites. Jekyll contains no login or registration functionality and is not designed to support it without a backend implementation.

Possible alternative to tomcat might be to host your jekyll site on [github pages](https://pages.github.com). Then your clients can login to github and use [prose.io](http://prose.io) to edit the content.

You can then use git to sync the repo with github and add a git hook to always get the latest changes and rebuild Jekyll for you tomcat.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying!